# How can I speed up this C# function / SQL insert?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

This code serializes an array of integers then inserts it into a sql table.  It isn't as fast as I need it to be.  Could I be doing anything more efficiently?

Thanks!

```
    public void SetItem(long Id, int[] items)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            foreach (int d in items)
            {
                var bin = BitConverter.GetBytes(d); //Serialize
                stream.Write(bin, 0, bin.Length);
            }
            var array = stream.ToArray();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Items(Id, Item, DateCreated) VALUES (@Id, @binaryValue, @dateCreated)", sqlConnection))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@binaryValue", SqlDbType.VarBinary, array.Length).Value = array;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Id;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@dateCreated", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = DateTime.Now;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping a BinaryWriter around the MemoryStream, rather than using a BitConverter? Also, since you convert it to a array in the end, why use a Stream rather than a array? You know the size already (items.Count * 4)

Comment: Is sqlConnection a private variable?

Comment: Yes, sqlConnection is a prvate variable.

Comment: I have heard that BinaryWriter uses BitConverter.GetBytes() internally.  Interesting point about the array.  Ill look into that, thanks.

Comment: @user404068: The code as posted doesn't look like it will run too slowly to me. Are you calling SetItem multiple times? Are you reusing the sqlConnection or opening a new connection each time. Can you provide some timings as to how long the first block (where you're converting the data) and the second block (where you are writing to the database) take to execute? It could be that the conversion is fast and the write takes longer (due to indexes on the table, for instance).

Comment: Claus posted some code that just about doubled the speed, but it appears to be gone now.  Sometimes I call it multiple times.  I reuse the connection. The first block takes longer.

Comment: There was a huge flaw in the code sample, as it wouldn't insert 75% of your bytes, so I removed it again when I realized the issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I advise you to divide this function in two. One regarding the byte array the other for insertion into the DB.

Then run profiling and see if you byte array code is slow or if it is a db problem.

Maybe you are trying to accelerate something that isn't slow :)

Answer (score 6):

If you're inserting a lot of rows, the `SqlBulkCopy` class is much faster than calling `insert` a lot of times.  See this [blog post for an example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikhilsi/archive/2008/06/11/bulk-insert-into-sql-from-c-app.aspx).

Comment: uhm... he's doind a single insert

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would try is preallocation of `byte[]` for memory stream:

```
var array = new int[BitConverter.GetBytes(0).Length * items.Length];
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(array))
{
    // ... rest is almost the same
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a procedure, with you insert command. It is faster because procedure is already compiled for Sql

Something like this:

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(actual_string);
conn.Open();

// Create the command string
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("EXEC insert_test @var1, @var2, @var3, @str1, @str2", conn);

// Iterate through all of the objects
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@var1", var1));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@var2", var2));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@var3", var3));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@str1", str1));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@str2", str2));

        // Read in all the data
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
} finally {
    conn.Close();
}
```

But my preference is to send a XML to a procedure.

You could see more in this [good article](http://www.tedspence.com/index.php?entry=entry090701-114812)

Answer (score 1):

My first inclination would be to pre-allocate an array to be used by the `MemoryStream`, and then use `BinaryWriter` to write to it:

```
var OutputArray = new byte[items.Length * 4];
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(OutputArray))
{
    using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(ms))
    {
        foreach (var i in items)
        {
            writer.Write(i);
        }
    }
}
// You can now send the OutputArray to SQL server
```

`BinaryWriter` does not use `BitConverter.GetBytes` internally. Rather, it extracts the bytes one at a time from the `int` and places them in a buffer. Then the buffer is written to the stream. `BitConverter`, on the other hand, allocates a new 4-byte buffer every time you call it.